# How to Migrate Azman store data from XML to SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azman

I have implemented AzMan Store in my application using XML.
But now I want to migrate it to SQL.

I have already lot of user roles and data in AzMan XML, can anyone tell me some utility or method through which I can migrates that data to SQL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I done that with [NETSQLAZMAN](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [AZMigrate](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/07/22/how-to-migrate-the-azman-store.aspx). You need to compile and run it. It is all explained in the blog.

Comment: this does not answer the question. AZMigrate migrates between XML and Active Directory. the OP asked about migrating to SQL Server.

Comment: AZMigrate can migrate to SQL Server as well. You just give a different command line parameter. I also used it myself successfully.

Comment: You are right, I just did it now. I guess I owe you an upvote then (too late to upvote here now).

Comment: @TsahiAsher any chance you could share *how* you did this? I can't find the download for with Windows 6.1 SDK anywhere..

Comment: @BenLaan, AZMigrate is in the [Windows 7 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), linked from the blog post Ako linked to. You only need to install Samples in the install wizard. If it gives a notice about having a later version of Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable than expected, uninstall it, and then reinstall the SDK (a known issue). If you are using Visual Studio 2010, you will have to reinstall it after that. AZMigrate is a C++ project, you will have to compile it to use it, e.g. with VS2010 (do the project conversion when you open it). finally, use a connection

Comment: string as described in [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770467%28v=ws.11%29.aspx) as the migration target. Good luck, you're gonna need it.